# How to end this loop properly?

Tags: loop

I´m using several similar loops to loop in content from different categories into different containers. If there are no posts in category X then it shouldnt open any container at all. Same with all loops.

I´ve done this before, I open the container after "have posts" and put the divs belonging to each posts after "the post". But this loop ends differently from what I´m used to, so I dont know where to end my container divs.

http://pastebin.com/BcVEse5v

How can I end the #wrapper-extra and .thumbnails properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's throw everything, but loop out:

```
if ($my_query->have_posts()) {

    // open container around all posts

    while ($my_query->have_posts()) :
        $my_query->the_post();

        // output for every post

    endwhile;

    // close containers around all posts
}
```

As you see:

- output of posts goes inside `while` loop as usual;
- opening larger containers is between checking `if` we have posts and `while`;
- closing larger containers should be after `endwhile`, but still inside `if` block.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I was confused about how I should type it in, but a friend helped me and showed that I can just close the php right after endwhile, close my divs and then start the php again. I´m not familiar with the syntax so I didnt know what to do or how to do it. Anyway, question is answered, thanks! (edit, seems I answered my own post - cant find where to move it)